# Python program to check whether a list is a valley or not

Tags: python

example of a valley:

9,6,5,4,10,13,40,55,68

The list must be strictly decreasing until one point and then after the list must be strictly increasing. Then it is considered as a valley.

constraints:

Use two pointer approach

Guys, I have come up with this code:

---

```
def isValley(n,j,n1):
    i = 0
    res = False
    while(i<j):
        if (n[i]>n[i+1]) and (n[j]>n[j-1]):
                n1.append(1)
        else:
            n1.append(0)
        res = n1.count(n1[0]) == len(n1)
        i+=1
        j-=1
    print(n1)
    if res:
        if(n1[0] == 1):
            print("Valley")
        else:
            print("Not a valley")
    else:
        print("Not a valley")

n = list(map(int,input("Enter the numbers : ").split()))
n1 = []
j = len(n)-1
print(n)
isValley(n,j,n1)
```

my code is working only when the no of elements on the left side of the element is equal to
the number of elements on the right side of the element.

please correct this and come up with a code that even satisfies irrespective of the number

of elements left of the element and right of the element.

hint:

I think i have issue while making comparisions

(Use Two pointer Approach only)

Please help me out guys

Comment: What is "two pointer approach"?

Comment: @ScottHunter: Presumably they're being taught to use an algorithm where they start from each end of the `list` and work inward until the values stop decreasing; if both end up at the same place, it's a valley, if not, it isn't. You'd use pointers for this in another language, so the name is probably riffing on that, even though in Python you're restricted to indices or iterators. They're probably expected to use indices since iterators hide too much from them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "my code is working only when the no of elements on the left side of the element is equal to the number of elements on the right side of the element." Okay, and what happens in the other cases? Did you [try to find the problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) "Use Two pointer Approach only". Okay. Does the existing code do that, according to your understanding? Did you try to write out the needed steps in plain English, and then verify them against the code? It's hard for other people to fix your code, because of the variable names.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just iterate from left to right (and from right to left), while the elements are strictly decreasing (increasing). Then it's a valley if and only if the pointers end up at the same location

```
def isValley(array):
    N = len(array)
    front_i = 0
    back_i = N-1
    while front_i < N-1 and array[front_i] > array[front_i + 1]:
        front_i += 1
    while back_i > 0 and array[back_i] > array[back_i - 1]:
        back_i -= 1
    is_valley = (front_i == back_i)
    return is_valley

print(isValley([9,6,5,4,10,13,40,55,68])) # prints True
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check that there is a strictly negative gradient followed by a strictly positive gradient. One way of doing this (using numpy) is:

```py
import numpy as np

def isValley(array):
    d = np.diff(array)
    return (
        np.array_equal(
            np.concatenate((np.argwhere(d < 0), np.argwhere(d > 0))).flatten(),
            np.arange(len(array) - 1)
        )
    )
```

Comment: Please don't suggest Numpy for something that wasn't using it, wasn't tagged that way, mentions a specific algorithm, and is almost certainly intended as manual algorithm practice or testing (i.e., a homework assignment, job interview question etc.)